# Connecting to Database using ODBC, Node, & Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, odbc

So, I have a proprietary database that can be connected to via ODBC driver. Someone on my team has confirmed that they can connect to the database using an ODBC driver in Microsoft Access and see the data inside of the database.

If possible, I would like to connect to this database using [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) but I am out of my element when it comes to ODBC drivers and how exactly they work.

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkMXJvaWeTE&ab_channel=UKDATASERVICE) video, I saw an example of someone creating an ODBC connection to a database (The video gives two examples. One for a Hive connection and another for MySQL) and then said person used Python to run queries on these connections.

Is there a way that I could do something similar with Sequelize?

I see that Sequelize supports MySQL so my hope is that I can use Sequelize to connect to MySQL, which has a connection to the proprietary database via ODBC, and run queries on the MySQL connection.

Is this possible? I feel like I might be misunderstanding how all of this ODBC stuff works.